# Ignore files or folders in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a `/builds` directory that has some compiled JS inside and I find myself accidentally editing files in there rather than the ones in the rest of the project that I want to edit because `Cmd-T` brings up 2 files and I just pick the first, quickly.

How can I ignore a file or a directory in my specific project in VS Code? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `settings.json`:

```
"search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/bower_components": true,
    "**/builds": true
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to also exclude them from the Cmd-t file search

Comment: Try using jsconfig (include or exclude options). Add this to your `jsconfig.json`: "exclude": ["node_modules", "builds"]

Comment: How can I find `settings.json` for the project or workspace? I only can open settings.json for the entire application, which I assume applies to all projects.

Comment: You can try typing `json` or `workspace` in Command Palette. For me the command is `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings`.

Answer (score 4):

What I recommend:

Create a file in the root of your application named `myProject.code-workspace` and edit it like this:

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "."
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "search.exclude": {
      "**/node_modules": true,
    },
    "files.exclude": {
      "**/android": true,
      "**/ios": true,
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true, // not needed
  }
}
```

In this way your project will ignore the files in the "explore" tab. if you want to exclude the files only for the search environment, add it to `search.exclude`, otherwise to `files.exclude` in the `settings` rules. You can add/edit as you want.

VSCode will detect that file and consider it as the JSON for the workspace config. Don't forget to open this workspace in your VSCode by going to `file > open workspace` and select this file.

For more info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 4):

The best way to achieve this for me was to instruct VScode to use the .gitignore file.
This prevents both the explorer view and searches to skip patterns matching the .gitignore.
In settings.json:

```
{
    "explorer.excludeGitIgnore": true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First open settings: in OSX "CMD + ,". Or go to the menu Code -> Preferences -> Settings. Or search "open user settings" in the commmand palette:
[image: Search settings in VSCode]

In Features -> Search press the **Add Pattern** button. Write your folder name, like the examples.

Important: If the folder has to be excluded for several projects, set this in the user tab (at the top of the screen), as a global setting. But, if this is only a one-time setting, switch to the workspace tab (next to User).